# What would be the culture of an advanced socially mature species?

Tags: society, magic, aliens, politics

The species is eusocial and incapable of stimuli such as adrenaline. They are highly affectionate, highly extroverted, can feel nirvana out of anything, are suppose to be masters at every social aspect.
In my head they'd be bored out of their minds of competition, sports and skill-based games.

What kind of entertainment, hobbies, past times would they enjoy?
Would they read fiction books and what kind and what genres?
Would they listen to songs, melodies and what genre? would they listen to lyrics and what kinda lyrics?
Would they absolutely hate dancing because its primitive?
Would they enjoy drawings or find it boring?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. I am afraid this question is purely based on opinions, and as such not suited for this site. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand our standards.

Comment: "Eusocial" is in direct contradiction with "highly affectionate" and "highly extroverted". The individuals of a an eusocial species have extremely attenuated identities by definition; that's what makes the species eusocial. There would be no fiction, no poetry -- those are manifestations of extreme individuality.